# Convert array to key value object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have this kind of array

```
['item one', 'item two', 'item three']
```

Ad would like to convert it to an object like this;

```
{
"name": 'item one',
"name": 'item two',
"name": 'item three'
}
```

I have tried looping through and creating a default key which i feel am not doing the right way

```
let arr = ['item one', 'item two', 'item three']
let obj = {};
arr.forEach((cv) => { 
  obj["name"] = cv; 
}
console.log(obj)
```

But this just returns an obj with the last value like this;

```
{
"name": 'item three'
}
```

Comment: What you are asking is not possible. There can't be duplicate keys. It also makes no sense to have duplicate keys in objects.

Comment: There is no such object, keys have to be unique. Setting `"name"` to `"item two"` will replace its previous content, `"item one"`. In other words: it is completely normal what you experience.

Comment: Is there any reason not to make `"name"` an array of items? I.e. `name: [ "item one", "item two", "item three" ]`

Comment: Or even using an array of objects [{"name": "items one"}, {"name": "item two"}, ...]

Comment: What are you actually trying to do, what would you need such a structure for? As other comments already pointed out, you cannot have a structure like this in JS — object keys must be unique. But what's unclear is why you need this structure to begin with, what's the end goal?

Comment: If someone ask you, what's your name so that they can call you with ? Will you tell him multiple name ? Similary, objects will not have similar name properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why same keys? for an object, keys should be unique.

instead, you can try this,

```
const arr = ['one', 'two', 'three' ]

let newArr = arr.map(item => {
    return { name: item } })
```

result

```
newArr = [
 { name: 'one' },
 { name: 'two' },
 { name: 'three' },
]
```